# MySQL datatypes not changing in PHPMyAdmin...?

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, I'm working on a php college project, and I have to let students register, submit their details- firstname, surname, phone number, id number, etc.

At first I used int for id number but I'm not going to do any math with it so I changed it to varchar, however after this change, all the examples I submitted still comes out with the maximum int value "2147483647" when I specified it to be varchar, why does this happen and how can I fix it.

If it helps the collation of the table fields are all latin1_swedish_ci.
I'm not a MySQL expert, so if there is any other info you need to get to the bottom of this problem just ask.

Edit: I also changed the fields' value back to bigint and it still throws 2147483647 in the table, even though I entered 8888888888888(13 characters), so with varchar or bigint i still get 2147483647, what am I doing wrong?

Update:I got the following error from phpmyadmin when trying to change the max value for the field.

```
  SQL query:

ALTER TABLE  `student` CHANGE  `idno`  `idno` BIGINT( 99999999999999 ) NOT NULL

MySQL said: 

#1439 - Display width out of range for column 'idno' (max = 4294967295)
```

Update: taking out intval() fixed this issue

```
 $id_number=intval($_POST['id_number']);
 $id_number=($_POST['id_number']);
```

Comment: If it's a numeric type, then leave it as an int/bigint. Just because you're not doing 'math' on the values doesn't mean you should ditch everything else that comes from keeping it as an int. How did you do this 'change'? `alter table`?

Comment: Also I don't have a dump of the Prof's database structure, so the php app should be portable, his just going to connect my code to his database.

Comment: In phpmyadmin I just changed the fields' datatypes, under the structure menu.

Comment: May be in the PHP code, the type of ID is bigint.

Comment: Changing the data type when storing numeric values impacts how ordering is performed.  And as others mentioned, VARCHAR(4+) takes more bytes than INT -- more bytes means slower when joining/searching/etc.  Most importantly, store data using the correct data type -- if you're not storing alphabetic characters in the column, do NOT use an alphabetic/alphanumeric data type -- there's no inherent validation.

Comment: Plus, you cannot have `AUTO_INCREMENT` behaviour with Char or Varchar columns.

Comment: With `ALTER TABLE` you alter table stucture, not assign new values to anything (someone correct me if I'm wrong). Just change the `idno` to (unsigned) `bigint` in PhpMyAdmin like you did earlier when you changed it from `bigint`to `varchar`. Then add `auto increment` to that column and reset it: `ALTER TABLE student AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `varchar` as ID unless you really need to use letters in the ID (PK?) field. It's faster to use integers. Maybe the PHP script is trying to change the DB's `varchar` to an integer so change the ID back to `int`.

Do you really need `bigint`? Unsigned `int` may be more than enough.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html

Update: If you need to make sure the value is an integer you should check it's datatype.

```
if(is_int($my_value)){
  //do the script
}
  else{
    //echo error message
  }
```

If the value comes from DB (column which's datatype is integer) everything should be OK but it never hurts to check...

Comment: Ok i just checked the type with gettype(), the type is integer in the php, and the field's type is varchar, but the value in the table is still 2147483647?

Comment: @grasshopper Change the DB datatype to integer and reset the auto increment if necessary. (You have the max `int` value in DB if I understand you correctly.)

Comment: You were right I had this in my php code $id_number=intval($_POST['id_number']); I guess the intval function caused the problems- cause everything is working since I took it out

Comment: @grasshopper Glad to know everything works. Again if I understand you correctly you used `intval()` to validate user submitted number. It shouldn't be done since it returns a value, it doesn't validate it (pass the correct value, label wrong one as `false`). Check i.e. PHP's filter functions for validating values: http://php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php